# console log of returned value shows a unusable response even after chaining a then to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

Im trying to return a promise is a javascript file. However, there is a weird issue. So when I console log the returned value within the function, it shows the following:

```
const id = getAccounts()
  .then(res => res.find(acc => acc.type === ACCOUNT_TYPES.STARTER))
  .then((res) => { return res.id });

  console.log(id.then(res => res))
```

[image]

Is there anything I am missing? Have been dealing with this and research for the whole day. If anyone can help, I would highly appreciate it!

Updated section:

```
const initialState = {
  currentAccountId: id.then((res) => { return res; }) || ''
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of calling a Promise's [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is always another Promise. By setting `currentAccountId` to `id.then`, it will always be a Promise.

You need to call `this.setState` from inside the Promise's resolve function:

```
componentDidMount() {
  getAccounts()
    .then(res => res.find(acc => acc.type === ACCOUNT_TYPES.STARTER))
    .then((res) => { this.setState({ currentAccountId: res }); });
}
```

Use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), like the React docs suggest, to initiate an async request. "If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request."

---

*Original answer*

*`id.then` will always return a new Promise, and that's what you are logging. To log the actual value you can move the `console.log` inside the resolve function:*

```js
id.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: hey, thanks so much for your response! However when I try to invoke it in my code with:

const initialState = {
  currentAccountId: id.then((res) => { return res; }) || '',
};

 instead of doing a console log , it crashes. Do you know if I need to do anything else to get this working here? I updated the post to show what I mean @Ross

Comment: You can ask a new question, but I will answer one more here. Updating...